# bind data in a grid from oracle server

Tags: android

I am a .net developer and now I have to work on android programming.
I know how to bind data in a grid view or repeater in asp.net but I don't know how to do it in android programming.

Actually, I want to show some data in a grid and the data exist on another oracle server. can anyone help me how could I get data from oracle server to my grid view in android?

Comment: start from learning "how to create and run android application", then "how to add GridView and fill it with data", then "how to download and parse JSON/XML/etc. data from remote server (possible using HttpUrlConnection or other net libs)". type this keywords to search and that's it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) Its a complete guide.

Few tips are here.

1. you have to write an adapter which is equivalent to data source/ datatable (which contains the data) in .net
2. getView overridden method acts like item_databound event in .net.
3. you fill the adapter and set it to grid.

Hope this will help.